# Flask URL decoding issue

Tags: python, flask

I have a url which has to be implemented which looks somthing like

```
/execute.php?SET 1 95
```

if I try to read everything using
`@app.route('/<string:command>')`

this returns only `execute.php` and nothing after that.
I cannot even treat it as parameters since there are no keys.

I have tried several variations and nothing seems to work.

What is the correct method to read the entire url in this case. I need to extract `SET 1 95` from the above url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url for the endpoint & then grab the string required

`from flask import request` -> to get url details for endpoint

`from urllib.parse import unquote` -> to decode the URL

Assuming your url is: `http://somewebsite.com/execute.php?SET 1 95`

`request.path` will give you `/execute.php`

`request.full_path` will give you `/execute.php?SET%201%2095` (here, `%20` is space & we need to decode this)

So, `unquote(request.full_path[len(request.path):])` will give you `?SET 1 95`